Golang private repo from windows
If you need to work with golang private repo, and you done with default steps:

go env -w GOPRIVATE=

GOPROXY=https://,https://proxy.golang.org,direct
it could be for example gitlab packages /api/v4/projects//packages/go

adding domain connection alias in  ~/.gitconfig, to convert golang https urls to git@... on git level
and have ssh auth (because you use domains in go.mod and we need some way to authorize)


[url "ssh://git@<your private repo domain>"]
    insteadOf = https://<your private repo domain>


Specify in ~/.netrc file with content for basic auth made by golang (after ssh auth)

machine <your private repo domain>
login <username>
password <password or token in case of gitlab>

But under WINDOWS this solution will not work
> go get <your private repo>/user/project
...
git ls-remote -q origin
...
        remote: ========================================================================
        remote:
        remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
        remote:
        remote: ========================================================================


Windows way is to create ~/_netrc file instead of ~/.netrc.
Tried use ~/.netrc and expecting it will be same on Windows as it works on Linux.
Is there cross system way to specify credentials?

Is there a question here?  It seems like you should put the last bit as an answer to your problem.  Right now this reads more like a blog post.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
